# CSS/HTML Menu going crazy

Tags: html, css

[image]

Hello Mates, 
I'm trying to build  a CSS menu that is displayed above. So far I wrote this HTML:

```
<div class="left-menu">
<ul class="menu-left">
    <li id="current" class="parent active item5">
        <a href="/teliani/index.php?option=com_telianiwines&amp;view=winesubcategory&amp;Itemid=5"><span>ღვინო</span></a>
            <ul>
            <li class="parent item6">
                <a href="/teliani/index.php?option=com_telianiwines&amp;view=winesubcategory&amp;Itemid=6"><span>TELIANI VALLEY</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="item7">
                            <a href="javascript:;"><span>ლეგენდა</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="item8">
                            <a href="javascript:;"><span>ღვინოები</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="item9">
                            <a href="javascript:;"><span>ჯილდოები</span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and this is my CSS:

```
/* 1 */
.left-menu ul {
    width: 145px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.left-menu ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.left-menu ul li {
    width: 145px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 20px;
    background:#fff;
}

.left-menu ul li a {
    width:131px;
    height:20px;
    padding-left: 14px;
    float: left;
    font: normal 12px calibri, sylfaen, georgia, arial, verdana;
    color: #7b2029; text-decoration: none;
}

.left-menu ul li:hover, .left-menu ul li#current  {
    width: 145px;
    height: 20px;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.left-menu ul li#current a {
    width: 131px;
    height: 20px;
    padding-left: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #7b2029;
    display:block;
}

/* 2 */
.left-menu ul li ul  {
    width:145px;
    padding:0;
    margin: 2px 0 0 0;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}

.left-menu ul li ul li {
    width: 137px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 8px;
}

.left-menu ul li ul li a {
    width: 120px;
    height: 20px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    font: normal 12px/20px calibri, sylfaen, georgia, arial, verdana;
    background:#887b33;
}


/* 3 */
```

and I'm getting displayed this crap:

[image]

Can someone tell me why? I haven't experience such thing before...

Comment: It's hard to say for certain without a live sample to study, but I'm betting that you've got some conflicting CSS rules.  Try inspecting it with the development console (F12 in IE 8, which you appear to be using) and see what CSS rules are applied.

Comment: Here's a fiddle from his supplied code for anyone to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/blineberry/Wjs3V/

Answer (score 1):

Link to example fiddle I have created:

[Fiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/6R5AL/)

I didn't bother with hover effects, and colors/font styles. You can always change it...
Tested on mozilla and IE (ain't got chrome at work).
I hope it helps.

Daniel

Comment: chrome looks fine here. Did you make any other changes than switching `padding-left` to `margin-left`?

Comment: I rewritten most of your code. Some styles are the same for all elements on all lists, all you have to do now to add another level/change any level is change margins on <span> elements and colors of links for a given 'level_' class... Everything else will lay out nicely.

Comment: Basically only main div has fixed width, everything inside is width 100%. It makes it easier to change if you need to. All ul and li elements have margins and paddings 0. Links are displayed as blocks instead of inline to stretch to 100% of a div width. Now every list is another level of a menu and so has appropriate class. Spans for every level have more margin on left to have that indented effect. Links on every level have different colors etc. This structure makes it very easy to edit and maintain.

Comment: thanks Daniel, actually I rewrote that already and it works fine.. don't know why it wasn't working.. haven't seen  such thing before, but hopefully I corrected that.  THANKS!!!